# Tuning sql by year

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have sql query like this where the input is `@year = 2017`
while the column format is `'2017-01-01 05:02:45.000'`. And I would like to tune this query because It has very long execution time.

```
DECLARE @Device_List VARCHAR(500) = 'MKV005, MKV007, NWTN01, NWTN03, QUEEN02, MKV009';

DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(20) = '2017'

SELECT MONTH(deduction_timestamp) as [Month],
      ISNULL(sum(fare_deduction), 0) AS total_fare_deduction
FROM [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[vClosingTransitLog]
WHERE bus_id in (select * from fnSplit(@Device_List, ','))
    and YEAR(deduction_timestamp) = ISNULL(@Year, YEAR(deduction_timestamp))
GROUP BY MONTH(deduction_timestamp)
ORDER BY [Month]
```

and would like to do like this

```
SELECT MONTH(deduction_timestamp) as [Month],
      ISNULL(sum(fare_deduction), 0) AS total_fare_deduction
FROM [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[vClosingTransitLog]
WHERE bus_id in (select * from fnSplit(@Device_List, ','))
    and (deduction_timestamp) >= '@year-01-01 00:00:00' and
 (deduction_timestamp) < '@year(plus one year)-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY MONTH(deduction_timestamp)
ORDER BY [Month]
```

But currently It doesn't work because of error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Can you guys help me? Really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (That code wont run on both products.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the year variable with the rest of your string, you can't embed it into the string.

```
deduction_timestamp < CONVERT(DATETIME, @year + '-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2):

I would re-write your first query as

```
DECLARE @Device_List VARCHAR(500) = 'MKV005, MKV007, NWTN01, NWTN03, QUEEN02, MKV009';

DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(20) = '2017'

SELECT MONTH(deduction_timestamp) as [Month],
       COALESCE(SUM(fare_deduction), 0) AS total_fare_deduction
FROM [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[vClosingTransitLog] c
CROSS APPLY (
      select * from fnSplit(@Device_List, ',')
      where bus_id  = c.bus_id 
)
WHERE (@Year IS NOT NULL AND YEAR(c.deduction_timestamp) = @Year) OR
      (@Year IS NULL)
GROUP BY MONTH(deduction_timestamp)
ORDER BY [Month]
```

Use ANSI SQL Standard  `COALESCE()` function instead of `ISNULL()`

Answer (score 0):

```
May be you want the see the output for year 2017 or later then I do not understand why are you using (deduction_timestamp) < '@year-01-01 00:00:00'
Please check this query:
     DECLARE @Device_List VARCHAR(500) = 'MKV005, MKV007, NWTN01, NWTN03, QUEEN02, MKV009';
        DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(20) = '2017'
            SELECT MONTH(deduction_timestamp) as [Month],
                  ISNULL(sum(fare_deduction), 0) AS total_fare_deduction
            FROM [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[vClosingTransitLog]
            WHERE bus_id in (select * from fnSplit(@Device_List, ','))
                and year(deduction_timestamp) >= @year
            GROUP BY MONTH(deduction_timestamp)
            ORDER BY [Month]
```